# YouCompleteMe Go: Navigating location list with a single error

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

The problem, step-by-step.

I'm using Vim with YouCompleteMe and vim-go plugins to edit a Go source file:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("foo")
}
```

I delete the `import` line, creating an error:

```
package main


  func main() {
>>    fmt.Println("foo")
  }
```

I want to jump to the line where the error is detected, so I `:lnext`, but get a message `E553: No more items`. Hmm...

With `:lopen` I can see that location list is populated alright, with a single entry regarding missing import. The problem is, vim assumes I'm "there" already (at the first entry), and doesn't move the cursor neither forwards nor backwards. Is there a way around this annoyance?

If there are more errors than one, I can navigate the location list as expected with `:lne`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using `:ll` does the trick in case of a single error.

Comment: With a single error, you’re already on that error in the location list. ll takes you to the current error. lnext takes you to the next, which doesn’t exist, as you noted. I use lfirst a lot because it always works to go to the first error.